# Using Navigational Topics with custom theme layout

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, customer-community, topics

We are building out a community using a net new "Theme Layout Component" for all of our pages. This page layout is using `<c:mainNav></c:mainNav>` per the tutorials on Trailhead. This pulls in our default nav just fine, but we want to use Navigational Topics. With the OoB Community themes, using Navigational Topics shows a drop down with the community topics. Why when creating a new Theme Layout does this not work? Am I supposed to use a different component?

OR - What can I add to my "mainNav" component that will apply ?

Screenshot of nav set up: 
[image]

Code for the mainNav.cmp

```
<aura:component extends="forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase">
   <div class="slds-grid">
       <ul class="nav-bar" onclick="{!c.onClick}">
           <aura:iteration items="{!v.menuItems}" var="item">
               <li class="{!item.active ? 'slds-is-active' : ''}">
                   <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-menu-item-id="{!item.id}" class="">
                       {!item.label}
                   </a>
               </li>
           </aura:iteration>
       </ul>
   </div>
</aura:component>
```